# Canary deployment using spinnaker in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, continuous-deployment, aws-application-load-balancer, spinnaker

I'm planning to do canary/Blue-Green Deployment in AWS ECS.
How to route the specific set of 10 % users to canary and I don't want those 10% users to go back to base line environment. Those 10% users should always be with canary version. Rest 90% users in production environment. If we use R53 or Load balancers it will split the traffic randomly. But I need to split the traffic to certain specified users to canary version, not random users.

I tried with R53 and ALB, but it's taking random users to route the traffic.
I need to route specific users to reach canary version and I don't want those users to go back to production version unless canary version is failed.

Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: This article would be a helpful reference - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/create-a-pipeline-with-canary-deployments-for-amazon-ecs-using-aws-app-mesh/